# MVC submit form more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-ajax

I have come across a weird issue, I hope someone can explain why the following is happening.

My controller:

```
MasterModel main = new MasterModel(); 

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult VehicleDetail()
{
    pageSessionSetup();
    return PartialView("VehicleDetail", main.Vehicle);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult VehicleDetail(VehicleDetailDisplay model)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Errors occured");
    main.Vehicle = model;
    pageSessionSetup();
    return PartialView("VehicleDetail", main.Vehicle);
}
```

**Updated With View**

My View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("VehicleDetail", "Operator", null, new AjaxOptions
{
   UpdateTargetId = "VehicleDetail",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
   HttpMethod = "Post"}, new { id = "VehicleDetail" }))
{
   @Html.Partial("_ValidationSummary", ViewData.ModelState)
   <div class="panel panel-default panel-body">
       ...
   </div>

   <div class ="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 row">
       <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-lg btn-green col-lg-2 col-md-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">Save</button>
   </div>
}
```

And on my partial view I have a submit button, but when I click the submit button one time then the form gets submitted more than one time.

Comment: can you please add view ?

Comment: Best guess is you have a submit button and your also submitting using ajax (and have forgotten to cancel the default submit action)

Comment: @StephenMuecke +1, but to not making us to guess, please provide your `View` code and `Js` codes (if you have).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE:

use `Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)` instead of `Ajax.BeginForm()` **OR** check if you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` twice in your page(s)(in partial views also).

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", ""ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    <label>SomeLabel</label>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Button" /></p> 
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary at all. One is marked `[HttpGet]` and the other `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Read my comment in the question :) - this code has nothing to do with a form submitting twice

Comment: I added `[ActionName("VehicleDetail")]` as indicated but my form is still submitting more than once.

Comment: @ArnoDT Please update your question with `View` code.

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm()` will not submit the form twice (OP still has not shown all the relevant code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Some time ago, I had `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>` script set inside my bundle and the view templates also included it, which resulted in double post's by the `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: @SeM: It looks like `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>` is also in my bundle and the `_layout.cshtml` also included it.  If I remove this, will it resolve my issue?

Comment: @ArnoDT Yes, I think so, that was solved my problem once.

Comment: @SeM: Thank you for all the help, when I removed it from the bundleConfig and added it on my main view that renders this partialview

Comment: I had a similar issue and the submit button was bound more than one time